# How do you keep track of your StackExchange involvements accross different sites?

Tags: discussion

I'm not 100% sure this is the place to ask this, but what tools (notifications over RSS, email, desktop widgets, browser plugins or something else entirely) do you use to keep track of what happens on this site (or any StackExchange site). By "what happens" I mean - new questions, new answers/comments to a question of yours, new meta discussions, etc.

I haven't seen anything that's worth attention, so I thought there might be something useful in this area.

Comment: You would probably get a much more comprehensive response from more users over at http://meta.stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some guy [George Edison](https://meta.askubuntu.com/users/5/george-edison) over at the [Ubuntu](http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com) SE made a [GNOME applet](http://stackoverflow.quickmediasolutions.com/stackapplet/stackapplet_1.2.0_all.deb) that shows your reputation and comments that you get. Can be used on any SE/SO site. I've tested it, and it seems to work (never got a comment in the meantime to see whether this functionality works, though).

[Here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/18/stackapplet-monitor-your-reputation-and-get-notified-of-comments) is the original post at the Ubuntu meta.